# Create files and dirs using QDir parent

Tags: qt

I'm new to Qt (previous experience is mostly Java) and am trying to find a good way of creating child directories and files given a QDir parent (and hold onto/create the QDir for the new child).

I've come up with a method to do this (I think!), but was unsure if this is the right way, or if there is already something built in that would do this for me.

Hope you can help.

```
QDir* MyClass::createChildDir(QDir* parent, QString dirName)
{
    parent->mkdir(dirName);
    QString newPath = parent->filePath(dirName);
    QDir* newDir = new QDir(newPath);
    return newDir;
}
```

Comment: I would not use dynamic allocation with QDir. Just return a QDir not QDir*. Also change the parameter `QDir* parent` to `const QDir & parent`

Comment: Thank you - I've updated my code.  Is there a good reference somewhere for learning about where to use and not use dynamic allocation?